# How do I fix a ASUS Eee PC to run Ubuntu 18.04 with "This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU"?

Tags: boot, kernel, asus, cpu

My son has an Eee PC and he tried to turn it into a Chromebook.

It did not work and the computer is stuck on trying to load chromium.  I asked an IT Tech at our school how to fix it. He suggested using Ubuntu. I downloaded Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and I tried to boot it from a USB drive and I received this message:

```
This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU
```

How do I fix it, so I can use the PC?  Do I need to do something different?

Answer (score 4):

Stock Ubuntu is 64 bit only but the flavors like Kubuntu and Lubuntu have 32-bit versions.

https://www.ubuntu.com/download/flavours

And for an old eepc you should use a lightweight OS like https://lubuntu.me/downloads/

Comment: +1 for trying Lubuntu, which is the Ubuntu community flavour with the lightest desktop environment. Another good alternative is Xubuntu. Both (Lubuntu and Xubuntu) provide 32-bit iso files (as well as 64-bit iso files).

Answer (score 1):

Even tho you didn't include PC specs, I'm guessing you're trying to install a 64 bit version of Ubuntu on a 32 bit PC. See if Ubuntu has a 32 bit, or i686, version and try installing again.